PowerRename RegEx to match filename BEFORE specified text
I am attempting to use Powertoys PowerRename to truncate the end of filename(s) after specified text, and then replace with additional text (perhaps this is beyond the functionality of this tool?).
e.g. I want to rename a file "abc_123_sometexttoremove(11).filename" to "abc_123_newtext_0001.filename"

I tried using the regex search term to match everything up to my specified text:
.+?(?=bar)

however, this works in reverse and instead starts from the back of the filename which is not what I want.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Do you need (?<=15\.00s).* ?

It does not work in reverse, it works as expected: removes all text from start till the first occurrence of 15.00s. What are the requirements exactly?

I thought because the example states "match everything up to xxx" that this meant all text would be kept till the first occurrence of 15.00s. I just need to do the opposite, take everything off the end of the filename after a certain point and append with my own stuff.

Look at my comment. That will match everything from xxx (in this case 15.00s) using a positive lookbehind

@VvdL this worked exactly to my needs, thank you!

@VvdL at first it didn't work but then I remembered I had to go and enable boost library

Do some research on regexs. Learn about capture groups. Learn about the difference between text matched inside a capture group compared to text matched outside of a capture group.
